# Is there a way to pass variables to decorator?

Tags: python, django

I have log in system, based on OpenID provider, and I want to create decorator like @login_required. But I have a problem - I need to check permission per object. I pass id to my views, so I want to know is there any way to pass it to decorator or it's impossible and I need to check users permission in my view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators). It's an old post, but it has a lot of good information on it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I'm looking for Django decorators so miss this article. It really helps me.

Answer (score 3):

```
def outer(var1, var2):
    def inner(func)
        func.foo = var1
        func.bar = var2
        return func
    return inner

@outer(myvar1, myvar2)
def myfunc():
    # whatever
    pass
```

While you can't pass variables directly to the function which decorates your function, you can create **another function** (`outer`) that, when called, returns the **decorating function** (`inner`). You pass the `outer` function variables, and they are available to the `inner` function. This is called a closure.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on when you need to do the stuff with the id you may need two levels of wrapping where you replace `print(permission_id)` with whatever it is you need to do before the method is called:

```
def login_required(permission_id):
    def decorator(func):
        def method(self, *args, **kw):
            print(permission_id)
            return func(self, *args, **kw)
        return method
    return decorator

class foo(object):

    @login_required('foo')
    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

foo = foo()
print('instantiated')
foo.bar()
```

Outputs:

```
instantiated
foo
bar
```

Comment: perhaps the most interesting thing is that defined function "method" is a **real method**. self reference behaves as expected, exposing a live object to play with.